# how would I return a instance of interface Infocard?

Tags: c#, interface

I am currently doing an assignment for my computer science course, however I have ran into a road block preventing me advancing any further. I am trying to return the InfoCard interface and I am unsure as to how.

```
public interface IInfoCardFactory
    {
        IInfoCard CreateNewInfoCard(string category);
        IInfoCard CreateInfoCard(string initialDetails);
        string[] CategoriesSupported { get; }
        string GetDescription(string category);
    }


public IInfoCard CreateNewInfoCard(string category)
        {

            ......
        }
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, please detail more...

Comment: You pick an implementation and send it back :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have an interface as your function return type but you most return an implementation of your class and the advantage of interface return type is you can return any inplementation of your interface
example:

```
interface ISampleInterface
{
    string SampleMethod();
}

class ImplementationClass1 : ISampleInterface
{
    // Explicit interface member implementation: 
    void ISampleInterface.SampleMethod()
    {
        // Method implementation.
        return "implementation1";
    }
}

class ImplementationClass2 : ISampleInterface
{
    // Explicit interface member implementation: 
    void ISampleInterface.SampleMethod()
    {
        // Method implementation.
        return "implementation2";
    }
}
```

and you can use that interface like this as function return type:

```
public ISampleInterface MyFunction(bool t)
{
   return t : new ImplementationClass1() ? ImplementationClass2();
}
```

that code means you can return different implementation of your interface by your choice

Answer (score -1):

Hope the following code will be useful.

```
public IInfoCard CreateNewInfoCard(string category)
{
    return new InfoCard();
}

public interface IInfoCard
{
    int foo { get; set; }
}

public interface IInfoCardFactory : IInfoCard
{
    IInfoCard CreateNewInfoCard(string category);
    IInfoCard CreateInfoCard(string initialDetails);
    string[] CategoriesSupported { get; }
    string GetDescription(string category);
}

public class InfoCard : IInfoCardFactory
{
    public IInfoCard CreateNewInfoCard(string category)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IInfoCard CreateInfoCard(string initialDetails)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string[] CategoriesSupported
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string GetDescription(string category)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int foo
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```